# How do I configure a single ASP .NET application to be hosted on multiple domains?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a single website that makes calls to multiple web-services, and the website is hosted in different environments, e.g:

```
https://production.domain.com
https://uat.domain.com
https://dev.domain.com
```

Each website calls out to webservices hosted in the same environment:

```
https://production.domain.com/rest/
https://uat.domain.com/rest/
https://dev.domain.com/rest/
```

How do I define my webservice URLs to be relative in the context of where the application is hosted? Do I require any IIS configuration to achieve this? 
The result would be:

https://production.domain.com => https://production.domain.com/rest

Having multiple combinations of URLs in my web.config and IF statements in my code is last thing I want to consider doing.

Answer (score 1):

If there's always a 1-to-1 relationship between the URL of the web service being called, and the URL of the request to the web application that's calling the web service then you should be able to compose the URL for the web service with relative ease. If you want a fully qualified URL, then you can start with the [`Request.Url`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the incoming request to the website and for example:

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
uriBuilder.Path = "/rest";
var uriForRestService = uriBuilder.ToString();
```

Using an instance of [`UriBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to preserve the protocol, host and also any custom port (e.g. if you're working with Visual Studio/IIS Express and thus have a `test.domain.local:4321` flavour of URL) although you could go down the route of just grabbing [`Request.Url.Authority`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority(v=vs.110).aspx) and constructing the rest of the URL yourself if you have a need to.